# Index and match a field name based off another table in Access SQL code

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access

I am using access to update some data values. I need to associate a number 1 to 50 to a numeric value associated with a trait from another table. The problem I am having is I need to index and match the two tables to match the two values then index the trait associated with the value. I can do this in Microsoft Excel with the following code...I would like to automate this process in access with a button but not sure how to index and match in Access.

```
=INDEX(B:B,MATCH(K:K,A:A))
```

In Access I've tried using an update query but index the trait value with the associated value is difficult without going into VBA code. The shd-50 and slk_50 have matching values to the Days after July 1st. I would like to update these values with the Daily HU value which are equivalent to Days after July 1st field. The GDUs_afterJuly1st are fixed values ranging from 1-50 and have a trait assigned to each number so 1=551, 2=638 ... 49 = 1440. While the tblFieldBook table I want to update the GDU_shd50 and GDU_slk50 with the 551, 638, and 1440.[image]

[image]

So the Yellow rows mean the GDUs_afterJuly1st and the Orange rows are the tblFieldBook. I would like to update the GDU_shd50 and GDU_slk50.

Comment: Edit question to post sample raw data and expected result as text tables instead of images.

Comment: Probably have to include GDUs_afterJulylst in query twice or run two separate UPDATE actions.

Answer (score 0):

I found this code was able to get the data I need. I just have some renaming that I would like to do of field names and table names. I will post this in the code when I figure that out.

```
Option Compare Database
Option Explicit


Private Sub Calculate_GDUs_Click()
   Dim StrSql As String
   Dim db As Database
   Dim fld As Object
   DoCmd.SetWarnings False

'run query to match and index GDUs to days after july
   StrSql = "SELECT * INTO GDU_slk_50 FROM tblFieldBook LEFT JOIN GDUs_afterJuly1st ON tblFieldBook.[slk_50] = GDUs_afterJuly1st.[Days after July 1st]"
   DoCmd.RunSQL (StrSql)
   StrSql = "SELECT * INTO GDU_shd_50 FROM tblFieldBook LEFT JOIN GDUs_afterJuly1st ON tblFieldBook.[shd_50] = GDUs_afterJuly1st.[Days after July 1st]"
   DoCmd.RunSQL (StrSql)
   StrSql = "SELECT GDU_shd_50.[Daily HU], tblFieldBook.* INTO [tblFieldBookwshd50] FROM GDU_shd_50 INNER JOIN tblFieldBook ON GDU_shd_50.recID = tblFieldBook.recID"
   DoCmd.RunSQL (StrSql)
   StrSql = "SELECT GDU_slk_50.[Daily HU], [tblFieldBookwshd50].* INTO [tblSlkShdGDUs] FROM GDU_slk_50 INNER JOIN [tblFieldBookwshd50] ON GDU_slk_50.recID = [tblFieldBookwshd50].recID"
   DoCmd.RunSQL (StrSql)
   StrSql = "DELETE tblSlkShdGDUs.[GDU_slk_50_Daily HU] FROM tblSlkShdGDUs WHERE (((tblSlkShdGDUs.[GDU_slk_50_Daily HU]) Is Null))"
   DoCmd.RunSQL (StrSql)

'delete tables not needed anymore
   DoCmd.DeleteObject acTable, "GDU_shd_50"
   DoCmd.DeleteObject acTable, "GDU_slk_50"
   DoCmd.DeleteObject acTable, "tblFieldBookwshd50"

'rename columns
   Set db = CurrentDb
   Set fld = db.TableDefs("tblSlkShdGDUs").Fields("GDU_slk_50_Daily HU")
   fld.Name = "GDU_slk50"
   Set fld = db.TableDefs("tblSlkShdGDUs").Fields("tblFieldBookwshd50_Daily HU")
   fld.Name = "GDU_shd50"
   Set db = Nothing
   Set fld = Nothing

'run export macro
   xlsxExport
   DoCmd.SetWarnings True
End Sub
```